# Python - Syntax error at end of input

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to extract data from excel to postgresql using python 3.6 and pgadmin 4. Here is a part of my code that is failing.

```
 if dataCentersName not in dataCenters:
                dataCenters.add(dataCentersName)
                query1 += "('" + str(dataCentersIdx) + "', '" + str(dataCentersName) + "'),"
                dataCentersDict[dataCentersName] = dataCentersIdx
                dataCentersIdx += 1
```

The error is at the comma after the last data center showing below
('8', 'DataCenter_8'),

It says:
Error %s % e syntax error at end of input

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can string variable you want to replace in your script: Look this example: v = 'your'; 'Hello wath's %s name' % (v)

Comment: And look again: query1 += ("%s %s %s) % (var_1, var_2, var_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a `,` at the end of your query, the query is awaiting for something else, that doesn't come hence the syntax error.

If you want to add a comma at the end of your loop as you're doing right now, you might want to send `query1[:-1]` (ignores the last character, the comma here), instead of `query1` that I am sure you are sending as is.

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed my code and forgot to add that part again!